# NGINX Mime Types

Tags: nginx, mime-types

I have the following problem:

https://my.domain.com/js/some_js_file.js

Is loading well but:

https://my.domain.com/some_other_folder/some_js_file.js

Brings up following error:

> Refused to execute script from 'https://my.domain.com/some_other_folder/some_js_file.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

This is now happening after a security update of our loadbalancer.

I tried several things.

Add:

```
location ~ \.js {
   add_header  Content-Type    application/x-javascript;
}
```

Or:

```
location ~ \.js {
   add_header  Content-Type    application/javascript;
}
```

changed `/etc/nginx/mime.types`

From:

```
    application/x-javascript              js;
```

To:

```
    application/javascript              js;
```

Nothing works and I don't get it that not all files are throwing this error. Only the files in `/some_other_folder/` or maybe outside of `/js/`

Comment: Have you managed to solve this? Having the same issue.

Comment: no not yet. sorry

Comment: How did you proceed?

Comment: in my case it is only when in development-mode and staging i loaded the single files outside of the /js folder in order to debug. on the live system it is loading the concat and minify version from of the /js folder. So i have more important things todo that's why i didn't solve until now