# Refused to execute script because strict MIME type checking is enabled

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, mime-types

I have setup an NGINX reverse proxy to a web service (www.aaa.com) through another domain name (www.bbb.com) while adding a few additional pages to the latter.

Request come from `www.bbb.com` (nodejs app) but they need to look like they are coming from `www.aaa.com` or I will have a CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing) issue. Hence NGINX to tweak the headers.

### NGINX config

```
worker_processes 1;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    include mime.types;
    include servers/*;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name www.bbb.com;
        ssl_certificate /etc/pki/nginx/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP 127.0.0.1;
            proxy_set_header Host www.aaa.com;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_pass https://www.aaa.com;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
        }
    }
}
```

Looks like one of the resources doesn't get the correct **MIME Type** through the reverse proxy
https://www.aaa.com/scripts/some.script.api.js

### Error

> Refused to execute script from 'https://www.bbb.com/scripts/some.script.api.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

`text/html` is incorrect indeed, I would be expecting `application/javascript`

**1. Why is this happening?**
I figured that MIME Types are just set automatically? Could that be that www.aaa.com has implement some new CORS security rule?

**2. Is there a way to tell NGINX to set the correct MIME Type for that particular file?** I have tried a few things to no avail.

e.g.

```
add_header Content-Type application/javascript;
```

but I may have used wrong. 
Any pointers?

Similar issue described on another [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39127614/nginx-mime-types)

Comment: Thanks for accept, and the bounty earlier.  So, what was the root of the issue in the end?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try using http://nginx.org/r/default_type; another thing that comes to mind would be http://nginx.org/r/proxy_hide_headers.

I would also suggest that the first line of action would be to determine the root cause of this issue — is the incorrect MIME type coming from your upstream?  Then look there.

Otherwise, my guess would be that the reason you're getting `text/html` is because something else is wrong with your configuration, and a [`404 Not Found`](http://ngx.su/src/http/ngx_http_special_response.c#ngx_http_error_404_page) response gets generated for your `.js` file (or maybe even `403 Forbidden` by the upstream, or `500` by nginx), thus resulting in the `text/html` MIME type.

Comment: The issue had evolved to `ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors www.aaa.com`. It would be too long to explain. HOWEVER your pointers lead me to hide the header containing that directive `proxy_hide_header "X-Frame-Options";` and that resolved my issue.